# Using Capital letter for a word in a sentence I want to put emphasis on?

Tags: writing, capitalization, emphasis

I sometimes tend to use the Capital letter for some words in which I would want to give emphasis on.

For example

> Please deliver the **Task** on Time.

I am trying to catch the users attention on how important the task and time is.

Is this correct usage?

Comment: You are not using **task** idiomatically. We do use the word **assignment** to mean both the assigned task and the results of your efforts, but its synonym, **task**, is not used in that way. A task is the job you have to do, not the product of your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using capital letters within sentences makes a writer seem uneducated and ignorant. One can use typographical effects such as italic, bold, underlining, etc, but even these should be used sparingly.

> ...use bold and italic as lit­tle as pos­si­ble.

[Bold or italic (Butterick's Practical Typography)](https://practicaltypography.com/bold-or-italic.html)

The Modern Language Association agrees (in my opinion this applies to bold as well):

> The MLA style discourages the use of italics in academic prose to
>   emphasize or point, because they are unnecessary—most often, the
>   unadorned words do the job without typographic assistance. And if they
>   don’t, then rewording is often the best solution. This policy is a
>   matter of stylistic convention, not grammar.

[Italics for emphasis (MLA Style center)](https://style.mla.org/italics-for-emphasis/)

Comment: Randomly capitalizing Words in a body of Text Makes it hard to read Quickly. Also, Capitalizing Unimportant Words is [sometimes used to denote sarcasm](http://the-toast.net/2015/06/22/a-linguist-explains-how-we-write-sarcasm-on-the-internet/ "A Linguist Explains How We Write Sarcasm on the Internet").

Answer (score 1):

Uppercase and italics are typical ways of emphasizing a word or phrase:

Please deliver this ON TIME.

Please deliver this *on time*.

Emphasizing "assignment" or "this" gets you nothing—is there something else that does not need to be delivered on time?— and actually weakens the emphasis you have placed on ON TIME.

Comment: An exclamation point might also do the trick: _Please deliver the task on time!_